# VBA Add button, set the caption and link it to a method

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a button on a new worksheet, set the caption and link it to a method in a module. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what type of button, Forms or ActiveX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Dim b As Excel.Shape
Set b = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlButtonControl, 10, 10, 100, 100)
b.OnAction = "AMacro"
b.OLEFormat.Object.Text = "Run a macro"
```

Comment: This works to insert a button but when I click on the new button it doesn't run the macro, it selects the button and highlights the caption for editing, also it runs the macro when its created I only need it ran when it is clicked? What am I doing wrong

Comment: @alyon2002 are you left clicking the button to run it, or right clicking which will bring up design mode?

Comment: Gserg, I realised at some stage I accidentally downvoted this by mistake as I scrolled the page. I have edited your post code formatting to remedy this. My apologies

Comment: I was right clicking, turns out I needed to left click and exit text edit mode, this worked great thank you

Answer (score 2):

<del>Try this taken from http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=43637</del>

```
Sub CreateButton()
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(199.5, 20, 81, 36).Select
    Selection.Name = "New Button"
    Selection.OnAction = "CheckTotals"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("New Button").Select
    Selection.Characters.Text = "Check Totals"
End Sub
```

**Edit:** GSerg's answer is admittedly better then this as this was just a quick copy and paste job for illustrative purposes. I will leave the answer up  as a comparative against a better way to programme VBA and a small reference as to why you should avoid `Selection`. I'd imagine the code snippet would be something produced via the macro recorder and clearly this will never be optimal.

Comment: Selecting things in Excel for acting on them is evil.

Comment: @Gserg Its certainly not optimal, but as its working code it didn't deserve the downvote (from whoever did that)

Comment: @alyon2002 Primarily as it is unncessary but it slows code down. It can also cause errors, ie the object may not be directly selectable (the worksheet may be hidden), it may trigger other `Event` driven code etc.

Comment: @Tom, I tried your example it it worked after I put Character.Text before ("New Button").select, thanks for the help!