# excel vba - automatically add/delete buttons depending on cell values

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm trying to do...

Get a button to automatically appear in cell H1 if there is something in cell A1. This is continued for multiple buttons down the column if more content is in the cells below A1. Each button when used will cut the contents of the cells from column A to G in the same row as the used button and paste them in the first blank row of another sheet and remove the used button.

First problem...

Adding a button in H1 if A1 is not blank. Remove/delete button in H1 if A1 is blank.

Edit 1:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(423.75, 0, 48, 15).Select
    'ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button1").Name = "Button1"
    Selection.Name = "Button1"
    Selection.Characters.Text = "REMOVE"
    With Selection.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=6).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem is using an if statement to put multiple buttons, each with the name "Button" followed by the number of what row its in (Button1, Button2, etc).

Edit 2:

Title change.

Old - excel vba - add/remove buttons and cell range

New - excel vba - automatically add/delete buttons depending on cell values

Comment: You need to demonstrate that you attempted to solve this problem yourself.  This site is for specific questions, it's unlikely that somebody will build something from scratch for you based on a vague scoping desire.

Comment: Also, since new people tend not to upvote or flag answers, spending our time answering questions such as these tends not to pay off.

Comment: I will post something I tried but it doesn't delete or add a button if I change what is in cell A1. Just hides it if blank or doesn't hide the button otherwise. @n8.

Comment: I'm someone that doesn't tend to vote because of the lack of experience and would rather not change the reputation of an answer or question due to my opinion about it.

Comment: I don't have a way to show an attempt to solve this myself because I can't get anything to work. I don't have much experience with vba. I just need what I have explained above the comments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250050/adding-command-buttons-to-worksheet-at-run-time-and-also-define-events,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163591/programmatically-add-several-buttons-to-an-excel-worksheet-with-vba,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949641/vba-add-button-set-the-caption-and-link-it-to-a-method

Comment: What you describe is a set of problems.  This merits a set of individual questions, not a single blanket question.  Most of us can appreciate the position you're in as we all started coding somewhere.  Please just focus your questions on specific problems.  You may find that 10 posts in you are building your reputation, becoming proficient, and becoming engaged with the community.  This is all good, so please take the time to do it this way.

Comment: I've listed the current problem as "First problem...". This is all I'm concerned with at the moment. I can't break it down more than this. I know there is multiple problems altogether in this but I'm trying to state what I want to do then the problems on the way.@n8.

Comment: I've tried recording a macro but its missing several things I need. What's missing is the if statements for the row the button is in to tell if the button should be add/removed. how would i write that into the macro? I have If cells(row(), 1) = "" Then ... this doesn't work

Comment: OK - then break that down: do you know how to check if a cell is blank?  "how would i write that into the macro" - look up the syntax for `If Then` in VBA, and try to use that to add something to your recorded macro: if you run into problems then post the code along with a description of what the problem is.

Comment: I can check if a certain cell is blank if it is supposed to be a certain cell. If it's a cell in a specific row then no. The blank cell can be in any row but only in column A

Comment: I would just like to say this is why I hate using forums. Showing the problem would be easier than trying to type out the problem(s).

Comment: How am I supposed to show my macro code in a comment? This forum thing is complicated to do that. Everything just shows as a paragraph.

Comment: added the code snippet to the post above under edit 1. @TimWilliams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the end result of what I was looking for. Thanks for all the help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim This As Worksheet, _
        RemoveButton, _
        ButtonName As String

    Set This = Sheets("SheetName1")
    ButtonName = "REMOVE" & Target.Row

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        If This.Range("$A$" & Target.Row) <> "" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            This.Shapes(ButtonName).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0

            With Target.EntireRow.Cells(1, "H")
                Set RemoveButton = This.Buttons.Add(.Left, _
                                                    .Top, _
                                                    .Width, _
                                                    .Height)
            End With

            RemoveButton.Name = ButtonName
            RemoveButton.Characters.Text = "REMOVE"
            RemoveButton.OnAction = "REMOVE_BUTTON_ACTION"
        Else
            On Error Resume Next
            This.Shapes(ButtonName).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

There are some bugs but they don't seem to be a big deal. For instance, if I paste multiple rows in column A then it only creates 1 button in the first row of the paste range.

```
Sub REMOVE_BUTTON_ACTION()
    Dim RemoveButton As Object, _
        ButtonColumn As Integer, _
        ButtonRow As Integer, _
        RemovedSheetRow As Integer

    Set RemoveButton = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)
    With RemoveButton.TopLeftCell
        ButtonRow = .Row
    End With
    RemovedSheetRow = Worksheets("SheetName2").Range("$J$1").Value + 1

    Range("A" & ButtonRow & ":G" & ButtonRow).Cut _
        Destination:=Sheets("SheetName2").Range("A" & RemovedSheetRow)
End Sub
```

I have a value stored in J1 for the number of cells containing something in column A. J1 actually contains a COUNTIFS() formula.

Again, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

This will add a button on any row where there's content in A1:A10, and remove any existing button (that was added by this code) if there's no content

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim c As Range, sht As Worksheet, btn, btnName As String

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    For Each c In sht.Range("A1:A10").Cells '<< cells to check for content

        btnName = "btnRow_" & c.Row 'name the button according to the row

        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            With c.EntireRow.Cells(1, "H")
                Set btn = sht.Buttons.Add(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
            End With
            btn.Name = btnName
            btn.Characters.Text = "REMOVE"
        Else
            'delete the button if it exists (ignore any error if not found)
            On Error Resume Next
            sht.Shapes(btnName).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: I added the code to the sheet and it's not working. @TimWilliams

Comment: It doesn't do anything. @TimWilliams

Comment: So you run it and nothing happens, even if there's content in A1:A10?

Comment: it only works if i add a button and assign that macro to it. I need it to work with  all of column A and automatically add or remove the buttons

Comment: This code will automatically hide or unhide a command button but I can't seem to modify it to work for what i want. I don't get it.`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Cells(1, 1).Value <> "1" Then
        Me.CommandButton1.Visible = True
    Else
        Me.CommandButton1.Visible = False
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub` @TimWilliams

Comment: I caught the difference. `Private Worksheet_Change(...)`. I put that in place of `Macro1()` in your code and it worked automatacilly. It still needs modification because it places multiple buttons on top of each other if a cell already has a value when putting in a value in a different cell. @TimWilliams